# Python: How to re-excute current code when handling exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I want to write to a sample crawler, so it can`t stop when crawling something,then I do like this:

```
def fun(arg0, arg1):
    try:
        pass
    except Exception, e:
        fun(arg0, arg1)
```

I`m really want to know, it`s a good idea,or how can I do better,thanks

Comment: `pass` cannot raise an exception. The `except` part of your function will never get executed. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, you`re right,'pass' was wrote wrong.....
I`m trying to do is that if the function raised exceptions I want to call the function again not stop or jump to next
My English is poor,can you clear that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the function call itself - that will lead to infinite recursion.

Instead, put the code in a loop.

```
def func():
   while there_are_things_to_do():

       set_up_for_work()

       try:
           result = do_something_that_might_fail()
       except SomeKnownExeptionType:
           handle_the_exception()
           continue                # Cannot use result, try next work thing

       do_something_with(result)
```

Comment: wow,it`s a good idea,but mostly the function just execute once,if add a 'while' statement will need an extra meaningless argument for stopping loop
thank you
By the way,i don`t think call the function itself in 'except' will make a infinite loop,because no exceptions no loops,is that right?